# How to ignore execution of method from custom attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I need to do nothing when method executed from not ajax. I know how to detect ajax request, but I don't know what I should return just for ignore.

```
public class AjaxOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
             filterContext.Result = ???;
        }
    }
}

    [AjaxOnly]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AjaxOnlyMethod()
    {
        //This is method should be ignore if not ajax request
    }
```

Comment: What would it mean to your app if it was not an Ajax call? If it's an error return an error response otherwise just return Ok().

Comment: [AjaxOnly] will filter all other calls and will only be called if the request is Ajax call. So you already have solved this. Every other request will not reach this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think you can redirect to some other action method like the one which returns an error view if the request is Ajax

like

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "SomeOtherActionMethodName" }));
```